# Compilation error when changing C# application from .NET Framework 4.5.2 to 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-framework-version

I have a C# application that works fine when compiled with a Target Framework of 4.5.2. However, when I change that setting in Visual Studio (Version 14.0.25424.00 Update 3) to 3.5 I get a bunch of errors and I am (obviously) not able to compile. Some of the errors I see have to do with trying to use the following namespaces and types:

1. System.Net
2. System.Xml
3. System.Security.Authentication
4. SslStream
5. X509Certificate2
6. System.Linq
7. System.Threading.Tasks

I saw some other posts about trying to modify the references and add a new System.Core library but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Some classes were not available in 3.5. I believe Tasks didn't arrive until 4.0.

Comment: Why are you moving the application from 4.5.2 to 3.5.1?  As others are saying here, there are many changes between those versions and yes you can move 3.5.1 to 4.5.1 easily,  moving backwards is a whole different beast.

Comment: The customer is saying they won't be able to migrate one system away from 3.5 for a while and they need to go live with this application. Believe me, I don't want to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove and re-add references to `System.Core.dll` and `mscorlib.dll`.

The `Task` class will not be available as it was only added in .NET 4.0. You could use the nuget package [Task Parallel Library for .NET 3.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary/) which is a backport of `Task` that works on .NET 3.5.

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question, but how do I readd the System.Core.dll and mscorlib.dll references? I see the references section on the right hand side of the IDE but I don't see how to add System.Core.dll.

Comment: @Hmmmmm you will need to remove them first, right-click on the reference and click Remove. Then re-add them by right-clicking on References and clicking Add References and then picking those two from the list.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. Originally I didn't see where to find System.Core but I found it. I don't see a mscorlib.dll referenced? Is that the same as Microsoft.CSharp?

Comment: Sorry replace the reference to System. Do any references have a yellow exclamation mark? Are there any Warnings in the Error List?